# Give the triple representation of a statement x:= y[i]

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, code-generation

Give the triple representation of a statement x:= y[i] I'm having a problem in this one

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be more specific about the context that you need the representation, [this](https://books.google.is/books?id=5ip7wthOSPkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA206#v=onepage&q&f=false) book has some good information about compiler design. Here is what it would look like using it's semantics.

```
   | operator | operand1 | operand2
1. |   []     |     y    |    i
2. |   :=     |     x    |   (1.)
```